# How early should I reserve Shinkansen tickets during April?

Tags: trains, japan, shinkansen

Is it enough to buy Shinkansen tickets at the day of departure or should I buy them several days in advance if I want to secure a seat? I'll be travelling between Osaka and Hiroshima during early April.

Comment: Remember there are non-reserved seats as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In April, the only period to watch out for would be [Golden Week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Week_(Japan)) at the very end of the month (April 29-May 5), when transport gets packed.  Early April will be fine though, and you'll have no problem reserving seats on the same day.

Comment: What if the Sakura happens to bloom in early April, does it affect travel by Shinkansen?

Comment: Not really. The cherry blossoms come to you, you don't need to travel to see them.  There are a few famous spots that do get some cherry blossom tourism (Kyoto, Yoshino), but not enough to fill shinkansen, and neither Osaka nor Hiroshima is on the list.

Comment: The [cherry blossom forecast](http://www.japan-guide.com/sakura/) currently estimates both Hiroshima and Osaka will bloom between April 3rd and 11th.